# How to import csv (local) into DB (on a server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, import-from-csv

I got the following query to import a `.csv` that works perfectly when I execute it on the SQL Server instance of my Microsoft SQL Server 2019.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Text;Database=D:\test\', 'SELECT * FROM test.csv')
```

However, if I copy/paste that same `test.csv` file to my desktop and try to import it using the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Text;Database=C:\Users\batman\Desktop\','SELECT * FROM test.csv')
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"

I understand that it probably is an access issue for the SQL Server to access my local network path, however, is there really no way to import files located locally to my database located on the remote SQL Server other than copying it in a location on the server itself?

PS: The reason I don't want to do this through the task / import function is that I'll have to perform this for several files and in an irregular but recurrent manner. So ideally, I'd like a query so I could eventually use it in a stored procedure.

Comment: You can use the [import wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-flat-file-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15) and it will allow you to select a local file.  Or, create a network share that's accessible to the service running SQL

Comment: "I understand that it probably is ..... to access my local network path":   Please define "local network path"

Comment: _is there really no way_ short answer - no. The engine will surely not have access to the personal folders of a specific user. You can use a network share - but the engine must have permissions to that location.

Comment: _The reason I don't want_ And the reason you MUST is because your design is based on and implemented within the database engine. You could use any simple ETL tool (like bcp) to import a file into a remote server without these issues.

Comment: Don't ever import from a use folder. Import from a standalone folder, it's less likely to have pathing/security issues. The problem could also just be that you don't have the ACE driver installed